# How to add paragraph dynamically in electron

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic, electron

I have an array of paragraphs

```
infoArray= [
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.microbreak'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.break'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.notif'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.tray1'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.tray2'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.tray3'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.setting1'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.setting2'></p>",
    "<p data-i18next ='userGuideInfo.setting3'></p>"
]
```

I want to display them one by one on button click. I'm using electron JS. My HTML arrangement and JS code is

```js
let infoDiv = document.querySelector('div[id=infoDisplay]')
let infoPara = document.querySelector('p[id=infoPara]')
infoPara.remove()
    
infoDiv.appendChild(infoArray[currIndex])
```

```html
<div id=infoDisplay>
    <p id="infoPara" data-i18next="userGuideInfo.microbreak"></p>
</div>
```

Can someone suggest how should I do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each element and either append the html or create a wrapper element and append the data. Here are a few approaches you can take, pick your favorite:

## Method 1

We can take advantage of [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) by using `beforeend` as the first parameter, and our html as the second parameter, this function will allow us to place the html in many different places which is why it is first on the list.

```js
let infoArray= [
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.microbreak'>1</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.break'>2</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.notif'>3</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray1'>4</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray2'>5</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray3'>6</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting1'>7</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting2'>8</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting3'>9</p>"
]

let infoDiv = document.querySelector('div[id=infoDisplay]')
let infoPara = document.querySelector('p[id=infoPara]')
infoPara.remove()
    
infoArray.forEach(item => {
    infoDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item)
})
```

```html
<div id=infoDisplay>
    <p id="infoPara" data-i18next="userGuideInfo.microbreak"></p>
</div>
```

## Method 2

Create a wrapper element and append it to the div. This utilizes `appendChild` like in your example.

```js
let infoArray= [
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.microbreak'>1</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.break'>2</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.notif'>3</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray1'>4</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray2'>5</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray3'>6</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting1'>7</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting2'>8</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting3'>9</p>"
]

let infoDiv = document.querySelector('div[id=infoDisplay]')
let infoPara = document.querySelector('p[id=infoPara]')
infoPara.remove()
    
infoArray.forEach(item => {
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = item
    infoDiv.appendChild(div)
})
```

```html
<div id=infoDisplay>
    <p id="infoPara" data-i18next="userGuideInfo.microbreak"></p>
</div>
```

## Method 3 (My least favorite way)

Append the data to the div using innerHTML. This removes the use of `appendChild` which your example uses.

```js
let infoArray= [
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.microbreak'>1</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.break'>2</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.notif'>3</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray1'>4</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray2'>5</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.tray3'>6</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting1'>7</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting2'>8</p>",
    "<p data-i18next='userGuideInfo.setting3'>9</p>"
]

let infoDiv = document.querySelector('div[id=infoDisplay]')
let infoPara = document.querySelector('p[id=infoPara]')
infoPara.remove()
    
infoArray.forEach(item => {
    infoDiv.innerHTML += item
})
```

```html
<div id=infoDisplay>
    <p id="infoPara" data-i18next="userGuideInfo.microbreak"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of them seems to work. I keep getting cannot remove null. Also I want to display only one para at a time. Why should I use a loop?